# How to avoid headings on certain pages?

Tags: header-footer, blank-page, scrlayer-scrpage

I am trying to remove the heading on the page I marked. Does anyone know, how to do this? Unfortunately, commands like \thispagestyle{empty} also remove the page number.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % F�r farbige Tabellenzellen
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcounter{tblerows}
\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{footnote}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}         
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % Erzeugen von Blindtext
\usepackage{booktabs}               % huebsche Tabellen % Subfigures
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % Farben
\usepackage{booktabs}               % hübsche Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\quelle}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Quelle:~#1}
\newcommand*{\EigeneAbbildung}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Eigene Abbildung~#1}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}


\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{flushleft}
    bblbl \ (B.Eng.)
\end{flushleft}
    
% der Titel der Arbeit:
\vspace{55mm}
\centering {Bachelor-Thesis\\ \vspace{5mm}
{{\LARGE{\textbf{dgentwicklung}}}}\\
    \vspace{2mm} 
    {{\LARGE{\textbf{tzhttem zur}}}}\\
    \vspace{2mm} 
    {{\LARGE{\textbf{Ragsdgsen}}}}\\\vfill}

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{l}
    Vorgelegt von:
\end{tabular}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    gg
\end{tabular}
    
\vspace{5mm}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
    f&G
\end{tabular}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{tabular}{l}
    Sankt Augustin, Februar 2021
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\section*{Sperrvermerk}
%\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace{8mm}
Die vorgelegte Bachelorarbeit mit dem Titel:
\begin{center}
    Fhtgfrhnf
\end{center}
beinhaltet vertrauliche und interne Daten des Unternehmens:
\begin{center}
    dgrbdf
\end{center}
Die Einsicht in die Bachelorarbeit ist Unbefugten nicht gestattet. Ausgenommen hiervon sind die Gutachter sowie berechtigte Mitglieder des Prüfungsausschusses. Die Vervielfältigung und Veröffentlichung der Bachelorarbeit – auch auszugsweise – ist grundsätzlich nicht erlaubt.
\\
Eine Ausnahme von dieser Regelung bedarf einer Erlaubnis des Unternehmens fthfraft. Diese Geheimhaltungspflicht ist auf fünf Jahre nach der Veröffentlichung der Arbeit begrenzt.

\vspace{28mm}
\parbox{6cm}{\centering\hrule\medskip Ort, Datum}
\vspace{3cm}
\hfill
\parbox{6cm}{\centering\hrule\medskip Unterschrift Student}

\parbox{6cm}{\centering\hrule\medskip Ort, Datum}
\vspace{3cm}
\hfill
\parbox{6cm}{\centering\hrule\medskip Unterschrift Unternehmen}
\vspace{3cm}
\cleardoublepage
\section*{Abstract}
fngf
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\thispagestyle{plain}` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work

Comment: Where do you want the page number to be located?  The best approach is probably to define a new page style, say "`numberonly`".  I'm not familiar with some of the packages you're using, so can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

If there should be a page number on pages with style `plain` too, you have to use

```latex
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
```

or its short version

```latex
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
```

If the blank page inserted by `\cleardoublepage` should use page style plain, you can load  package `scrextend` and use `\cleardoubleplainpage`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
  headheight=13.6pt% <- added to avoid the warnings regarding the head height
]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{scrextend}% <- added

\usepackage[headsepline,automark,
  singlespacing=true% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}% <- changed, or do you want \ihead{\leftmark}?
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}% replaced by option singlespacing=true

\usepackage{titlesec}% load after scrlayer-scrpage
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% load last:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section*{Sperrvermerk}
\cleardoubleplainpage% <- changed
\section{Abstract}
fngf
\end{document}
```

If all blank pages should use page style page style `plain`, you can load package `scrextend` with option `cleardoublepage=plain`:

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
  headheight=13.6pt% <- added to avoid the warnings regarding the head height
]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage
  [cleardoublepage=plain]% <- added
{scrextend}% <- added

\usepackage[headsepline,automark,
  singlespacing=true% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}% <- changed, or do you want \ihead{\leftmark}?
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}% replaced by option singlespacing=true

\usepackage{titlesec}% load after scrlayer-scrpage
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}

% load last:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoubleemptypage%<- changed
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\section*{Sperrvermerk}
\cleardoublepage
\section{Abstract}
fngf
\end{document}
```

**Additional remarks**:

If have removed the unrelated stuff from the preamble. But do not load packages twice. With `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` package `colortbl` must not be loaded. Package `xcolor` loads package `color`. Class `article` does not provide chapters. So `\chaptermarkformat` is undefined. `\chapterpagestyle` is not provided by standard classes, its a KOMA-Script command. Load package `titlesec` after `scrlayer-scrpage`. Load packages `hyperref` and `cleveref` last, but in this order.